# nginx configuration for robots.txt

Tags: nginx, robots.txt

I've read other answers and Nginx docs, and I can't figure out why this works:

```
location = /robots.txt {
    alias /<fullpath>/static/robots.allow.txt;
}
```

and this don't:

```
location = /robots.txt {
    rewrite .* /robots.allow.txt last;
}
```

for the second one, server root is `root /<fullpath>/static;`

Comment: The `rewrite...last` will search for a new location to process the rewritten URI. If you use `rewrite...break` the rewritten URI is processed within the same location.

Comment: You're right, it worked, thanks! Though I have another question, when the request is processed a new file `robots.txt` is created in the very same location, why does that happen?

Comment: I have never seen that. What does the file contain?

Comment: The very same content

Comment: @richard some CMS have custom instead standard path used thats like you would use htaccess to fix this url ;)